# Save progress of users in powerapps and it doesn't start with new instance everytime same user opens the app

Tags: powerapps

I have created an new joiner onboarding app for my team in PowerApps. I am using an excel connector to add data in a collection. This collection is then used to create a list of to-do-tasks. I am giving user the option to mark a task as completed (i.e. patch the relevant row in my collection). I am not updating records in my excel file because that is a common data source for all new joinees.

Now, everytime the user exits and restarts the app, the collection gets loaded from scratch and all the progress (tasks completed are reset).

Is there a way to save the progress of these tasks per user basis?

PS: I know one way is to create outlook tasks (by using o365 user profile) from the powerapps and load it everytime. But I don't want to use Outlook tasks.

Answer (score 0):

PowerApps Collections are **temporary** data store. Think of them as an in-memory type of table which is wiped when the user closes the app. You will need a proper Data Source to store records beyond the user session. There are MANY options. The easiest is a Sharepoint list.

Just like you're Patching the Collection from the spreadsheet, you need to have the user "Submit" their data and Patch it to a proper, longer term Data Source.